# How do I delete a custom keyboard shortcut in Windows 7 when the program is no longer there?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My cat set a shortcut on the keyboard to iTunes without me realizing it, and I deleted the program.  When I reinstalled it, the keyboard shortcut remains, but I cannot figure how to turn it off.  Now when the lowercase letter "B" is typed, iTunes opens.  How do I turn this off when "None" is listed for the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Shortcut keys require atleast 3 key combinations (like Ctrl + Alt + B) which you can assign in shortcut properties. Do you have a hotkey tool  like AutoHotKey or similar running in the background, per chance? I wonder how your cat managed to set a hotkey that way - 8 cats here.. no issues :)

Comment: That's one smart cat.

Comment: I don't know what we did, but I tried repeating actions that I knew she and I did, and the shortcut finally just isn't working.  Yay!   If I have a hotkey tool running in the background, I don't know what it is.  All I care about is it's turned off.  For now at least.  I have no idea what happened, what we did, etc.  This is the first time that we ever managed to get something weird going.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find iTunes in the **All Programs** menu.
2. Right click and select **Properties**.
3. In the **Properties dialog**, find the text box labeled “**Shortcut key**”. Check if lowercase **b** is in the text box. I'm not sure if you can just delete it but try and tell me if it works.

Regards

Comment: Fortunately for me, the shortcut turned off before I got a chance to check this method.  As of now, it says "None" in the shortcut key.  Hopefully, it'll stay this way.